# Acessar impressora local

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, impressão

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma aplicação [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) e preciso imprimir etiquetas em uma impressora que está instalado no computador do cliente, como faço para imprimir estas etiquetas diretamente pelo browser, enviar direto na porta?

Comment: Pode usar o dialog de impressão do browser?

Comment: Não, é preciso enviar direto para a porta, pois a impressora só aceita arquivo .EPL e dispensa a visualização do usuário.

Comment: Não dá pra acessar a impressora diretamente por JavaScript.

Comment: Existe alguma solução para enviar diretamente do browser a etiqueta que o servidor gera?

Comment: Só se você criar um plugin pro browser, e o plugin cuidar disso.

Comment: Qual impressora é essa? eu imprimo em uma Zebra GC420 direto pelo browser usando um print da página.Crio uma página em bco apenas com uma imagem gerada dinamicamente da etiqueta, chamo o método print() e o usuário já tem a impressora como padrão. Mas também temos um aplicativo que consulta uma fila de impressões e faz as impressões conforme a resposta do @AlexTakitani

Comment: É uma impressora TLP 2844, mas do seu modo, abriria o diálogo de impressão do browser e eu não gostaria disso, vou fazer como o @AlexTakitani falou, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [este](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) plugin para fazer a impressão no cliente.
Coloque a pasta **jre6** em seu public e altere o código:

```
function deployQZ() {
    var attributes = {id: "qz", code:'qz.PrintApplet.class', 
    archive:'jre6/qz-print.jar', width:1, height:1};

    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'jre6/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp', 
    cache_option:'plugin', disable_logging:'false', 
    initial_focus:'false'};

    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == true) {}
    else if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == true) {
         attributes['archive'] = 'jre6/qz-print.jar';
         parameters['jnlp_href'] = 'jre6/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp';
    }
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
}
```

Com isso ele vai conseguir listar todas as impressoras do computador do cliente e assim poder imprimir o que quiser nelas.

Porém um requisito é que o cliente tenha instalado o jre 7, e é necessário dar permissão no painel de controle do java para que possa ser executado o seu código java.

Veja os exemplos do plugin para entender melhor.

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 1):

O **browser** não tem acesso direto a impressora, eu resolveria da seguinte forma:

Criaria um aplicativo desktop, que seria instalado no computador do cliente.

Este *app* faria *queries* em uma fila de impressão ( banco de dados, api rest, etc. ) e imprimiria as etiquetas.